# Flot: Barchart Shadow

Tags: javascript, flot

Is it possible to use shadow on barcharts? 
I've seen that there is an option "shadowSize":

```
series:{
color: color or number
data: rawdata
label: string
lines: specific lines options
bars: specific bars options
points: specific points options
xaxis: number
yaxis: number
clickable: boolean
hoverable: boolean
shadowSize: number
highlightColor: color or number
}
```

I've tried to changed this value but nothing happened. I also tried to change the lineWidth ("lineWidth" is the thickness of the line or outline in pixels. You can set it to 0 to prevent a line or outline from being drawn; this will also hide the shadow.) inside "bar":

```
     bars: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            barWidth: 0.2,
            align: "left",
            horizontal: true,
            show:true,
            fillColor: { colors: [ "rgb(64, 31, 33)", "rgb(55, 26, 28)", "rgb(52, 25, 27)", "rgb(102,49,52)", "rgb(102, 49, 52)", "rgb(195, 139, 143)", "rgb(87,42,45)" ] }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way for bars, in the [source code](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.js#L2528) there's even a comment about this:

> // FIXME: figure out a way to add shadows (for instance along the right edge)